# Jquery datatable : Dynamically manipulate the aoColumns attributes

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a requirement in which I need to change the data-table data and headers based on the radio button selection. The response is made available by an AJAX request. We can easily change the data by using API function. But I need to change the column properties (specifically sTitle,mData) as my response have different keys for each of the radio button selection.

For the first radio button my response is:

```
 {"id" :101, "label" : "Ragesh"}; headers - Id, Label ,
```

Second radio button response:

```
  {"type" :2 , "name" :"Ravi"} ; headers - Type, Name
```

Please tel me how this can be accomplished without recreating data-table

If any clarification is required, I can provide more details

Any kind of help is highly appreciated !!!

~Ragesh

Answer (score 1):

There is one very tricky workaround based on hidding columns.

Make following steps to initialize table. 
First define "aoColumns": with four columns:

```
"aoColumns": [
    { "sTitle": "Id",   "mData": "id" },
    { "sTitle": "Label" "mData": "label" },
    { "sTitle": "Type", "mData": "type" },
    { "sTitle": "Name" ,"mData": "name" }]
```

Then define ajax source, for example, for the first radio button case:

```
"sAjaxSource" : "/getFirstAjaxSource";
```

After table initialization, set 3 and 4 column ( in your case "Type" and "Name" ) as invisible using jQuery, so you will see only first and second columns:

```
 $(function(){
  oTable.fnSetColumnVis( 2, false);
  oTable.fnSetColumnVis( 3, false );
})
```

Then in click handler functions use following logic.

First button:

```
jQuery('#first').live('click',function () {     
  oTable.fnSettings().sAjaxSource  = "/getFirstAjaxSource";      
  oTable.fnSetColumnVis( 0, true);
  oTable.fnSetColumnVis( 1, true );
  oTable.fnSetColumnVis( 2, false);
  oTable.fnSetColumnVis( 3, false );
});
```

Second button:

```
jQuery('#second').live('click',function () {     
  oTable.fnSettings().sAjaxSource  = "/getSecondAjaxSource";      
  oTable.fnSetColumnVis( 0, false);
  oTable.fnSetColumnVis( 1, false );
  oTable.fnSetColumnVis( 2, true);
  oTable.fnSetColumnVis( 3, true );
});
```

Don't forget to add fake values ​​for hidden columns in the ajax source.

Comment: Thanks Smiter for your quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

At-last I managed to find a solution .
     I initialized the table with the first two columns, specifying a class for each column with "sClass" attribute for ,say(Id, Label) and based on radio button selection, first I changed the header text of both columns accordingly. For the data, what I have done is I parsed  the response and created a unique format for both cases.

Let me make it more clear:

**Datatable initialization:**

```
$('#myTable').dataTable({
"aoColumns": [  {"sTitle": "Label", "mData": "column1_data","sClass" : "header1"},
        {"sTitle": "Type", "mData": "column2_data","sClass" : "header2"},
                        {"bVisible" : false, "mData" : "id"}],
        "sScrollY": "150px",
        "aaData": [],
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bfilter": false,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bAutoWidth":true,
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "oTableTools": {
            "sRowSelect": "multi",
            "aButtons": []
        }       

    });
```

Then I parsed the response and made a unique data-structure for both cases like below:

**Function which returns unique response for both cases:**

```
function getData(aaData){ // aaData -> data obtained from server
var returnData = new Array();   
$.each(aaData, function(index,rowData){

    var row = new Object();
    if(firstRadioBtn){
        row['column1_data'] = rowData['label'];
            row['column2_data'] = rowData['type'];
    }else{
        row['column1_data'] = rowData['sourceLabel'];
        row['column2_data'] = rowData['targetLabel'];
    }
    row['id'] = rowData['id'];
    returnData.push(row);
    }); 
    return returnData;

}
```

This is how I solved it..I would like to know if this is good...

Suggestions are always welcome !!!

~Ragesh